# Cant get RTSP stream - nonmatching

Tags: opencv, stream, video-streaming, rtsp, openalpr

I'm using Raspberry Pi3 and I`m trying to get a RTSP stream through my wireless IP camera, but I'm getting this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ alprd -f
INFO - Running OpenALPR daemon in the foreground.
INFO - Using: /etc/openalpr/alprd.conf for daemon configuration
Missing config value for company_id
Missing config value for pattern
INFO - Using: /home/pi/Database/pictures for storing valid plate images
INFO - country: br -- config file: /etc/openalpr/openalpr.conf
INFO - pattern: 
INFO - Stream 1: rtsp://192.168.1.230:554/onvif1
INFO - Starting camera 1
INFO - Video stream connecting...
[rtsp @ 0x71700960] Nonmatching transport in server reply
WARN - Stream rtsp://192.168.1.230:554/onvif1 failed to open.
INFO - Video stream connecting...
[rtsp @ 0x71700840] Nonmatching transport in server reply
WARN - Stream rtsp://192.168.1.230:554/onvif1 failed to open.
INFO - Video stream connecting...
[rtsp @ 0x71700960] Nonmatching transport in server reply
WARN - Stream rtsp://192.168.1.230:554/onvif1 failed to open.
INFO - Video stream connecting...
[rtsp @ 0x71700840] Nonmatching transport in server reply
WARN - Stream rtsp://192.168.1.230:554/onvif1 failed to open.
INFO - Video stream connecting...
[rtsp @ 0x71700960] Nonmatching transport in server reply
WARN - Stream rtsp://192.168.1.230:554/onvif1 failed to open.
INFO - Video stream connecting...
[rtsp @ 0x71700840] Nonmatching transport in server reply
WARN - Stream rtsp://192.168.1.230:554/onvif1 failed to open.
```

The RTSP link that I´m using is:
rtsp://192.168.1.230:554/onvif1

or with the user:pwd is:

rtsp://2512398:123@192.168.1.230:554/onvif1

The way it is in my alprd.conf:

```
; Declare each stream on a separate line
; each unique stream should be defined as stream = [url]

stream = rtsp://192.168.1.230:554/onvif1
;stream = http://192.168.1.36:8080/video
;stream = http://127.0.0.1/example_second_stream.mjpeg
;stream = webcam
```

I can connect using VLC (in my computer and RPI) without any problems, but when I use it in my .conf file in order to use the command **alprd -f** to start checking for license plates I get that error :/

I'm really a novice in programming, so please don't go way too specific because I will probably not understand it hahaha

Thanks guys! Love u all <3

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem, try `ffplay -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp//:...` if you get same error you need to change opencv `ffmpeg_cap_impl.hpp` source, because this param hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

At **OpenCV 3.4.1** you can change env variable *OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS* to "rtsp_transport;0".

This env var is taken into account in cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp.

```
#if USE_AV_INTERRUPT_CALLBACK
    /* interrupt callback */
    interrupt_metadata.timeout_after_ms = LIBAVFORMAT_INTERRUPT_OPEN_TIMEOUT_MS;
    get_monotonic_time(&interrupt_metadata.value);

    ic = avformat_alloc_context();
    ic->interrupt_callback.callback = _opencv_ffmpeg_interrupt_callback;
    ic->interrupt_callback.opaque = &interrupt_metadata;
#endif

#if LIBAVFORMAT_BUILD >= CALC_FFMPEG_VERSION(52, 111, 0)
#ifndef NO_GETENV
    char* options = getenv("OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS");
    if(options == NULL)
    {
        av_dict_set(&dict, "rtsp_transport", "tcp", 0);
    }
    else
    {
#if LIBAVUTIL_BUILD >= (LIBAVUTIL_VERSION_MICRO >= 100 ? CALC_FFMPEG_VERSION(52, 17, 100) : CALC_FFMPEG_VERSION(52, 7, 0))
        av_dict_parse_string(&dict, options, ";", "|", 0);
#else
        av_dict_set(&dict, "rtsp_transport", "tcp", 0);
#endif
    }
#else
    av_dict_set(&dict, "rtsp_transport", "tcp", 0);
#endif
    int err = avformat_open_input(&ic, _filename, NULL, &dict);
#else
    int err = av_open_input_file(&ic, _filename, NULL, 0, NULL);
#endif
```