# How to fix opencv python cv2.VideoCapture rtsp onvif "nonmatching transport in server reply" error?

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, rtsp, onvif

I am on Windows and using Python 3.6.4.  I've installed OpenCV (3.4) via pip. Here is the code I am using:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://192.168.15.116:554/onvif1')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[rtsp @ 03858a40] Nonmatching transport in server reply
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:808)
warning: rtsp://192.168.15.116:554/onvif1 (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:809)
```

I can go to `cmd` and type

```
ffplay rtsp://192.168.15.116/onvif1
```

and the video will run as well as in VLC using the same rtsp address. Using

```
cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

also works with my webcam.

I've tried copying the file "opencv_ffmpeg340.dll" into all path folders but to no avail. I've also checked build and all video I/O show up with "YES" except for Gstreamer. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: any progress on this issue? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @nttrung143 maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66280861/1207193) might help

Answer (score 1):

I installed OPENCV onto Windows 10 using Microsoft's VCPKG.  After which, OPENCV worked fine - except it would not open videos files.

Without success, I tried many suggestions.  Finally, what worked for me was very SIMPLE.  I included opencv's BIN folder as a PATH in Windows Environment System Variables. That's it. Now, video files are opened and played just fine.

Comment: When you say "video files" does that include (or better if exclusively) onvif rtsp videos?

Comment: @ProjetosPrinceTower - Thank you for calling me out on this.  I should have been more specific.  My tests were successful with MP4, AVI, and RSTP.

I tested RSTP videos using the following URL and it streamed in just fine.
capVideo.open("rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov");

Comment: I see, unfortunately I can also run rtsp protocol with a video file specified like that. My issue is specifically with my onvif webcam. But thank you anyway, I'm sure it will be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this problem and after digging it looks like OPENCV 3.1+ defaults to TCP for the RTSP transport (my ESCAM QF600 only supports RTSP over UDP). You can prevent this from happening via setting the environment variable OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS to something (e.g. dummy).

For completeness; see https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html for all options that can be set. Keys and values are separated with ';' and pairs are separated via '|'.

The offending code begins at line 809 in cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp
(https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp)

Props to the following posts for sending me in the right direction:

[ffmpeg rtsp error: Nonmatching transport in server reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554594/ffmpeg-rtsp-error-nonmatching-transport-in-server-reply)

[Cant get RTSP stream - nonmatching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229086/cant-get-rtsp-stream-nonmatching)

Comment: Can you please give me some guidance on how to set that environment variable? Is it in the code, parameter when running the program, operational system?

Comment: Hi, I was just experimenting with node+opencv on Windows so I just needed to do `set OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS=dummy` on the command line before running my node app for it to work. If you're running an server application/service in python you could look into os.environ in the python os module to set it in your program if it's an issue setting in your OS.

Comment: I was wondering if this could be achieved in a python script before calling cv.VideoCapture