# Can't get an Opencv, cv2.VideoCapture rtsp steam to work from IP camera

Tags: opencv, rtsp, openrtsp

I am trying to read a rtsp stream from my Ip camera using Opencv and running Linux.  The camera is a Floureon IPC 360  from China. I am trying to develop some facial recognition code.

I am using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

vcap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.1.240:554/realmonitor?channel=0")
print(vcap)
while(1):
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    print (ret,frame)
    cv2.imshow('VIDEO', frame)
    #cv2.imwrite('messigray.png',frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

$ python  w.py
<VideoCapture 0x7fc685598230>
(False, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "w.py", line 9, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('VIDEO', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

cv2.imshow is failing as the frame is 'None' & (ret is False).

In a separate window I can run openRTSP :

```
./openRTSP  -4 -P 10 -F cam_eight -t -d 8 rtsp://192.168.1.240:554/realmonitor?channel=0
```

Which creates me a nice mp4 file that I can play:
107625 Sep 12 19:08 cam_eight-00000-00010.mp4

OpenRTSP works with or without the t (tcp).
I have also tried supplying the admin:123456  credentials to the cv2.VideoCapture line, which openRTSP doesn't appear to require.

Any ideas why cv2.VideoCapture is apparently failing ?

I have tried variants of the above code, but nothing seems to work.
I have enabled ONVIF on the camera

Answer (score 0):

According to other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49221676/2369389), it isn't possible to acquire ONVIF streams with OpenCV, since it defaults the stream to use the **tcp** protocol, while ONVIF relies on **udp**. 
You should define the environment variable `OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS` to skip the default setting to tcp, as can be seen in the original source code [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp#L879):

```
OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS=whatever
```

If you want to properly configure the capture options, then you should refer to the `ffmpeg` [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#Protocol-Options), which is used internally by OpenCV.
As stated in the linked answer, keys and values are separated with `;` and pairs are separated via `|`.

Comment: Hi, Apologies, but I think that I need some clarrification.   Are you saying that I need to disable ONVIF on the camera ?   Also,  why and how do I need to set the OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS environment variable ?   Would this variable be set from the Linux Bash shell or from within Python ?   The documentation says that setting OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS  disables TCP/IP transport.   Why would I need to do this ?   Could you be explicit in what I have to do to my camera,  the above code  and Bash environment please ?

Comment: I have modified my python code to include:  import os

os.environ['OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS'] = "dummy"                           but to no avail.

Comment: @UnrealAdmin i've added more clarification